# Is it possible to svn checkout in a database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, svn, visualsvn-server

I a writing a little webapp, which allows the users to browse through a Visual SVN server. I would like to add an online editor like github in this webapp, so users can edit the files online, leave a message and the changes appear in the repository.

For that I need to checkout the files locally. My idea was to check them in a mongodb out, so I can save the changes per user like a local working copy.

Is there a way (without reimplementing the svn protocol) to make a checkout in a database or even just the memory and then write it in the database.

If there are any questions, just ask :)

Btw. if someone is interested, here is the code https://bitbucket.org/Knerd/svn-browser

Comment: What about using `svnmucc`? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.working-without-a-wc.html

Comment: Sounds nice, I just checked around and seems to be exactly what I need :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do `svn checkout` to directly to database. But there is some options.

First of all, you can simple create virtual disk that resides in memory and perform checkouts to that disk. Than you can store checked out files to database.

Another option is to use rich Subversion API directly. Note, that Subversion is written in C, so you will need to build bridge between Node.js and SVN (as far as I can remember, there is no official Subversion bindings for Node.js, but there is for Python and Java and there is unofficial [nodesvn](https://www.npmjs.org/package/nodesvn) package available for Node.js). Using the API you can implement your own 'in-database' working copy.

Also you can use `svnmucc` utility (which is shipped with VisualSVN Server) to make commits directly in the repository (without even making a working copy). If you combine it with `svn ls`, `svn info` etc. you can implement repository browsing and editing of files.

Comment: Thank you, I gonna try it later :)